# Is there any way a UDP checksum could be inconclusive of error detection?

Tags: tcp, udp, layer4, checksum

If I am receiving data through UDP, with a checksum that checks out to show no data loss, is there a possibility that the checksum missed some errors. My data transmitted is split into 24-bits chunks by the protocol that uses the checksum. Similarly, if errors are detected through the checksum, does that fully guarantee that the error actually occured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the optional (for IPv4, but required for IPv6) UDP checksum, then that creates a 16-bit checksum that conceptually matches multiple combinations of datagrams that are larger than 16-bits. There is no guarantee that a UDP datagram that matches the checksum is error-free, but the odds of an error are very small. Many errors that would match the checksum would prevent the datagram from reaching its destination.

If the checksum indicates an error, then something is wrong somewhere, and it is almost always corruption in the datagram. Other possibilities include an incorrect or buggy checksum algorithm on the part of the sender or receiver.

If you mean a checksum in the application data, that further protects the data, but that is off-topic here.

There are also the possibilities that bits get flipped in RAM or on a disk drive. It does happen, but not very often.

See [*RFC 768, User Datagram Protocol*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt):

> Checksum is the 16-bit one's complement of the one's complement sum of
>   a pseudo header of information from the IP header, the UDP header, and
>   the data,  padded  with zero octets  at the end (if  necessary)  to 
>   make  a multiple of two octets.
>
> The pseudo  header  conceptually prefixed to the UDP header contains
>   the source  address,  the destination  address,  the protocol,  and
>   the  UDP length.   This information gives protection against misrouted
>   datagrams. This checksum procedure is the same as is used in TCP.
>
> ```
>               0      7 8     15 16    23 24    31 
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |          source address           |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |        destination address        |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>              |  zero  |protocol|   UDP length    |
>              +--------+--------+--------+--------+
> ```
>
> If the computed  checksum  is zero,  it is transmitted  as all ones
>   (the equivalent  in one's complement  arithmetic).   An all zero 
>   transmitted checksum  value means that the transmitter  generated  no
>   checksum  (for debugging or for higher level protocols that don't
>   care).

Comment: With large transfers over bad networks the TCP/UDP checksums are nowhere near strong enough to reliably prevent corruption.

Comment: This is correct.  The algorithms in use are a trade-off between performance and acceptable performance in the context of the original specs of these protocols.  In practice it's proven to be good enough in the majority of cases but there's no question that app-level sanity checking is never a bad idea.  There's also the interesting phenomenon that encryption can serve as an excellent error-detection mechanism.

Comment: Also, I think it will be pretty evident that there is a problem when there are a lot of checksum errors. It is very unlikely that all UDP datagrams will pass the checksum when a lot of the datagrams are damaged. I wouldn't trust any data if there is even one percent of datagrams not passing the checksum.